# Bootstrap columns?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a problem with bootstrap columns. When I am zooming-in browser then columns overlapping each other and text from `col-md-7` is at the image.

Is there any solution for this problem?

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-5">
     <img id="imgs" src="http://eeee.com" width="120" height="120">
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-7">
     <h3><b>Emma T.</b></h3>
     <p><b>Text</b></p>
     <p class="datetxt">TEXT</p>
     <p class="datetxt">TEXT</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Setting a specific size for an image, inside a relative container is a good formula for errors. When zooming in, you actually make the `window` width smaller, and therefor decreasing the size of the column. Though the image's size remains the same since it's statically set to 120x120 pixels...

Comment: Thank you, i didnt notice that.

Answer (score 1):

The columns should stack when you zoom in since it's changing the viewport width on which Bootstrap @media queries are based. Make sure you use `img-fluid` in the images to make it responsive. Also make sure the scale is set in your document HEAD tag, otherwise nothing will be responsive:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

https://www.codeply.com/go/A6e4GIO7CM

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <img id="imgs" src="http://placehold.it/620" class="img-fluid">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <h3><b>Emma T.</b></h3>
        <p><b>Text</b></p>
        <p class="datetxt">TEXT</p>
        <p class="datetxt">TEXT</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, having a set width & height image inside of a bootstrap col alone is a bad idea, I'd suggest changing it to:

```
<img id="imgs" src="http://eeee.com" style="max-height: 120px;" class="img-fluid">
```

Adding the class of `.img-fluid` causes the image to scale up/down to fit correctly within the col & container.

I hope this helps!

Comment: That's invalid HTML! `max-height: 120px;` is CSS.

Comment: They happen sometimes :)